# bash: [D:\\software\\miniconda\\Scripts\\conda-script.py,: No such file or diretory

Tags: anaconda, git-bash

I am trying to activate conda environment in git bash. however, whenever I open the git bash, I came up with the error:
`bash: [D:\\software\\miniconda\\Scripts\\conda-script.py,: No such file or directory.`

and when I try to activate the environment, I got the following errors:

```
$ conda activate pytorch

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 138, in main
        return activator_main()
      File "D:\software\miniconda\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 1094, in main
        print(activator.execute(), end='')
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xcf' in position 1047: illegal multibyte sequence

`$ D:\software\miniconda\Scripts\conda-script.py shell.posix activate pytorch
```

The `conda activate [env_name]` code works fine in cmd, and I can find the `conda-script.py` in `D:\\software\\miniconda\\Scripts\\`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I solved it by deleteing one Chinese system path in my system environment variables.
Maybe it is because there are some special characters in your system environment path. You might need to check your system variables, delete the path which includes special characters and reboot the git bash.